# Python 3: Issue writing new lines along side unicode to text file

Tags: python-3.x, text, unicode, newline, file-writing

I ran into an issue when writing the header of a text file in python 3. 
I have a header that contains unicode AND new line characters. The following is a minimum working example:

```
with open('my_log.txt', 'wb') as my_file:
    str_1 = '\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\n\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588'
    str_2 = 'regular ascii\nregular ascii'
    my_file.write(str_1.encode('utf8'))
    my_file.write(bytes(str_2, 'UTF-8'))
```

The above works, except the output file does not have the new lines (it basically looks like I replaced '\n' with ''). Like the following:

```
████████regular asciiregular ascii
```

I was expecting:

```
████
████
regular ascii
regular ascii
```

I have tried replacing '\n' with u'\u000A' and other characters based on similar questions - but I get the same result.

An additional, and probably related, question: I know I am making my life harder with the above encoding and byte methods. Still getting used to unicode in py3 so any advice regarding that would be great, thanks!

**EDIT**
Based on Ignacio's response and some more research: The following seems to produce the desired results (basically converting from '\n' to '\r\n' and ensuring the encoding is correct on all the lines):

```
with open('my_log.txt', 'wb') as my_file:
    str_1 = '\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\r\n\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588\u2588'
    str_2 = '\r\nregular ascii\r\nregular ascii'
    my_file.write(str_1.encode('utf8'))
    my_file.write(str_2.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I think it would have been better to change to text mode with an encoding and let Python change `\n` if and when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `'wb'`

The file is open in binary mode. As such `\n` isn't translated into the native newline format. If you open the file in a text editor that doesn't treat LF as a line break character then all the text will appear on a single line in the editor. Either open the file in text mode with an appropriate encoding or translate the newlines manually before writing.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned wanting advice using Unicode on Python 3...

You are probably using Windows since the `\n` isn't working correctly for you in binary mode.  Linux uses `\n` line endings for text, but Windows uses `\r\n`.

Open the file in text mode and declare the encoding you want, then just write the Unicode strings.  Below is an example that includes different escape codes for Unicode:

```
#coding:utf8
str_1 = '''\
\u2588\N{FULL BLOCK}\U00002588█
regular ascii'''

with open('my_log.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as my_file:
    my_file.write(str_1)
```

You can use a four-digit escape `\uxxxx`, eight-digit escape `\Uxxxxxxxx`, or the Unicode codepoint `\N{codepoint_name}`.  The Unicode characters can also be directly used in the file as long as the `#coding:` declaration is present and the source code file is saved in the declared encoding.

Note that the default source encoding for Python 3 is `utf8` so the declaration I used above is optional, but on Python 2 the default is `ascii`.  The source encoding does not have to match the encoding used to open a file.

Use `w` or `wt` for writing text (`t` is the default).  On Windows `\n` will translate to `\r\n` in text mode.

Comment: Very helpful - Thank you!